# Dygraphs "x axis" has in-between range

Tags: graph, intervals, dygraphs

I am building a linear graph with Dygraphs. I have "1 2 3 4" on x axis, and "12, 55, 23, 18" on y axis. When I plot the graph, the tick has in-between number.

For example between 1 and 2 I can see 1.5 on the x axis. I want to have the exact intervals as I specified up as 1 increment. Is there a way to fix this problem ? How to do this in Dygraph ? This is an example :

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="dygraph-combined.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="graphdiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  g = new Dygraph(

    // containing div
    document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
    // CSV or path to a CSV file.
    ("Response Time,Loop\n" +
    "01,175\n" +
    "02,170\n" +
    "03,180\n" +
    "04,177\n" +
    "05,179\n"+
    "06,165\n")
  );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in support for this (you should star [issue 368](https://code.google.com/p/dygraphs/issues/detail?id=368)). But you can simulate it by defining an axisValueFormatter which returns the empty string for non-integers:

```
axes: {
    x: {
        axisLabelFormatter: function(num, gran, opts, g) {
            if (num == Math.floor(num)) {
                return Dygraph.numberAxisLabelFormatter(num, gran, opts, g);
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Fully-functioning demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/1682/).